# How to trigger a batch file on my local system from Jenkins which is on cloud?

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have certain limitation  due to which I will have to stick with my local machine from which my IOS device will be connected where I will be running automation.
I will be having a batch file which I want to execute via Jenkins which is there on cloud.
Could you guys please suggest on how to proceed with the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Just got clarification: Your issue is that you cannot connect you local machine to Jenkins or that you cannot run the script? What error do you get?

Comment: I have a batch file on my local machine which triggers automation on my iPad.
I wanted to create a job for the same on Jenkins which will trigger the same batch file.
But the problem is jenkins is on cloud where as this is a local machine.
So i just wanted to know if there is a way to do that.
Note: I have achieved the same when the Jenkins is on my local server... nut the same thing is not working for the jenkins that is there on cloud.

Comment: I assume you’re not the admin of that cloud Jenkins instance you’re talking about? You will need to get you local machine connected to Jenkins as a build agent. Depending on your local network setup this may involve changing your this setup and / or your firewall rules.